# How to replace any string with a concatenation of another string and one field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, string-concatenation

I'd like to replace ANY string (empty or whatever) in field1 with a concatenation of myString + field2. How can I do it?

This is what I tryed and it doesn't work:

```
UPDATE table SET field1 = REPLACE(field1, '%', CONCAT(myString, field2));
```

I guess the problem is the '%' since I don't know how to match ANY string.

Comment: I assume you really mean `myString + field1`.

Comment: Sorry I edited the post.

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this as:

```
UPDATE t  -- this is the name of the TABLE, not the COLUMN
    SET field1 = CONCAT(COALESCE(mystring, ''), COALESCE(field1, ''));
```

The `%` is a wildcard character used only for `LIKE`.  It is not some sort of general wildcard.  If you want to concatenate two other values:

```
UPDATE t  -- this is the name of the TABLE, not the COLUMN
    SET field1 = CONCAT(COALESCE(mystring, ''), COALESCE(field2, ''));
```

Of course, `COALESCE()` is only necessary if you want to treat `NULL` as an empty string (otherwise `CONCAT()` returns `NULL`).

Comment: Ok, it worked like a charm. It's the first time I see this function, really interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET field1 =  CONCAT(myString, field2);
```

> The CONCAT() function concatenates two or more expressions together.
>
> syntax
>
> CONCAT(expression1, expression2, expression3,...)

```
 OR
UPDATE table SET field1 = CONCAT(COALESCE(mystring, ''), COALESCE(field1, ''));
```

> MySQL COALESCE() function returns the first non-NULL value of a list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.
>
> it will make empty '' when there is no value in mystring.
>   for more info http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php

Comment: UPDATE table SET field1 = CONCAT(COALESCE(mystring, ''), COALESCE(field2, ''));